# binding udp socket to ipv6 address only

Tags: java, sockets, bind, ipv6

I'm wondering how can I bind a UDP-socket to IPv6 loopback by executing the following code:

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = 
    new DatagramSocket(5000,Inet6Address.getByName("::1"));
```

I get following netstat output, the socket bound to IPv4 as well as IPv6 address.

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:5000           *:*                                    2932
UDP    [::1]:5000             *:*                                    2932
```

But when I try following code for TCP instead of UDP

```
new ServerSocket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(
    InetAddress.getByName("::1"), 5000));
```

I get the socket bound to IPv6 loopback address only

```
TCP    [::1]:5000             [::]:0                 LISTENING       3856
```

Comment: What happens if you explicitly bind() the UDP socket with `bind(SocketAddress addr)`after creating it?

Comment: Following code gives "SocketException : already bound"
new DatagramSocket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 5000));
don't know why.

Comment: Probably [IPv4 mapped IPv6 addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses).

Comment: @Sushant: the parameterless constructor binds the socket to an IP wildcard and port 0 (ie any IP on any port), that is why `bind()` is raising an "already bound" exception. In order to call `bind()` manually, use `new DatagramSocket(null)` instead.